# VB comments in completion box

Tags: vb.net

I do not understand vb comments. I read that it is possible to give a hint in the code completion box when someone (or myself?) is using my code. But I do not find something in visual studio. Could you please give a short explanation how to get there.

Answer (score 3):

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx) MSDN magazine article about code comments to understand how these work.

And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzysab5k.aspx) is the how to.

Simply put, you use three `'` characters with the XML comments for them to be used as code comments (`'''<summary>Summary of my code</summary>`).

Answer (score 3):

The feature you're asking about is called "XML Documentation Comments". [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx) discusses them from the VB.Net perspective. From the article:

> XML comments for Visual Basic were first introduced in Visual Studio 2005. They can be used to create a documentation file for the project, and provide a rich development environment experience for yourself, your teammates, or other people using your code.

Example:

```
''' <summary>
''' This function does really cool stuff.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="foo">The foo to work with</param>
''' <returns>True on success, False on error</return>
Public Function CoolThing(ByVal foo As String) As Boolean
' ...
End Function
```

...but don't worry, you don't have to type those `summary`, `param`, `returns` things yourself, the editor helps you with them.

Answer (score 0):

this is easy, you need only three times the commment marker, like: '''

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to see how it works / looks

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    IllustrateComments() 'fix this statement to see how this works
    Dim foo As Boolean = IllustrateFunctionComment() 'fix

End Sub

' Most of this is Auto Generated by typing three ' 
''' <summary>
''' This is the summary block
''' </summary>
''' <param name="firstParameter">This is a description of the first parameter</param>
''' <param name="secondParameter">This is a description of the optional second parameter</param>
''' <remarks>*** Some remarks ***</remarks>
''' <exception cref="Exception"> *** Exception here ***</exception>

Private Sub IllustrateComments(ByVal firstParameter As String, _
                               Optional ByVal secondParameter As Integer = 0)
    '
    Try

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Summarry of the function.  Note the return
''' </summary>
''' <param name="param1">param1 description</param>
''' <returns>returns a boolean - DUH!</returns>
''' <remarks>*** Some remarks - see object browser to see full benefit ***</remarks>
Private Function IllustrateFunctionComment(ByVal param1 As String) As Boolean
    Return True
End Function
```

I found these two links helpful

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172653.aspx